# Block access to media folder

Tags: magento-1.9

I was checking through URLs and found that mydomain.com/media is giving public access to upload and download files from the server without restriction.
I tried adding the code in htaccess file to restrict access but it is restricting my theme to access the images and media too from the folder.
the code that i used:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

My current htaccess is as below kindly suggest some edit that would restrict direct access but allow theme to access the media folder.

```
Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 0
</IfModule>

# AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
Options -ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* ../get.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Since that **is** the purpose of the media folder (unlimited download of images by browsers so they can be viewed on the pages), is there a specific subfolder you are trying to limit access to? As to images and your theme, maybe a referrer requirement as in a hot-linking block? Image indexers (google, bing) and your CDN will need acccess as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about server administration, not Magento.

Comment: Agreed. I found it later. Sorry did not update it here.